# Why isn't my Redux state structured correctly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In `CatsPage.js`'s `mapStateToProps` function, the output for `console.log(state)` is displaying:

```
Object
    Cats (Object)
        Cats (Array)
```

When the nesting I want is:

```
Object
    Cats (Array)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**setup.js**

```
import cats from '../reducers/catReducer';

let store;

const initStore = ({onRehydrationComplete}) => {

  store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer(),
      cats
    }),
    {},
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history),
        apolloClient.middleware()
      ),
      autoRehydrate(),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
  );

  persistStore(store, {
    blacklist: [
      'form'
    ]
  }, onRehydrationComplete);

  return store;
};
```

**catReducer.js**

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  cats: []
}

export default function catReducer(state = initialState.cats, action) {
  return state
}
```

**CatsPage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CatList from './CatList';
import {loadCats} from '../../actions/catActions';

class CatsPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('CatsPage: componentDidMount');
    this.props.dispatch(loadCats())
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Cats</h1>
        <div>
          <CatList cats={this.props.cats} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CatsPage.propTypes = {
  cats: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {

  console.log('mapStateToProps')
  console.log(state)

  return {
    cats: state.cats
    //cats: [{id:1, name: "Maru"}]
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CatsPage);
```

Comment: Instead of `{ cats: [] }` as initial state, have you tried just having an array: `const initialState = []` and in the reducer `state = initialState`?

Comment: @AndrewLi nice, that worked! Is that the right way to do it? As you can probably tell, I'm a newbie to react-redux...

Comment: That's okay :). Yes, using an array is the correct way to do it. The thing is `combineReducers` shapes state according to keys passed to `combineReducers`'s first argument. The object `initialState` is basically creating an extra object and nests the array which isn't good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're structuring your initial state is causing the unwanted nesting you see. Instead of using an object as initial state, just use an array to get rid of the nesting:

```
const initialState = [];
```

And set initial state of the reducer like so:

```
function catReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    ...
}
```

Since `catReducer` only controls *its* slice of state, it only controls the array of cats. Thus, it's initial slice of  state should just be the array, not an object holding an array; that ruins the desired structure.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

The following code segment is wrong

```
export default function catReducer(state = initialState.cats, action) {
  return state
}
```

`state = initialState.cats` is setting `state` to an array. If you want it to be an object you should do `state = initialState`.